# How i can pass POST parameter with redirection

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have a simple link, i want to pass the parameter data in "location".

I i delete the redirection i can see in my console that the parameters (data POST) have been passed but if i redirect in my console i received nothing.

```
// Search Reg
$('.search_reg').click(function(){
var test = "test";
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'catalogue_search.php',
            data: {'test': test},
            success: function (data) {
        var url = "catalogue_search.php";
            $(location).attr('href',url);
            }
           });
});
```

Comment: i don't want to use a submit button or something

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: $(location).attr('href',url); what is this line doing there..

Comment: It's not clear from the code or the problem description.  But it *sounds* like you're making a POST request to the server, and the server responds with a redirect for the browser?  But then it's not clear how your AJAX code is involved.  Please elaborate.

Comment: In my page catalogue_search, i have a variable $test which contain $_POST['test']; , in another page i want to send test for using the value of POST in my catalog.

Comment: when you are using ajax ... why you want to redirect ??

Comment: You're already requiring a click, why not have that click submit a form, then the act page that the form is pointing at does the redirect? That's the normal way this kind of functionality is handled. If there's a redirect involved, it's better to do a postback than ajax.

Comment: Because i have two pages. The first one there is a link, when i click on this link i need to send a value in "catalogue_search.php" and a rediretcion directly .

Comment: so, you post to catalog_search.php, then you redirect to it? that  doesn't make sense!

Comment: i want to post to catalog_search.php and going directly to this page. If i delete the location "test" will be posted, it's fine but i stay in this page.

Comment: you can try this:

catalogue_search.php?test=test

Comment: Like a GET but with a POST !

Comment: i received my value with another way in POST

Comment: so you dont have any form, you want to post data directly

Comment: i have to ? <a href="#" class="search_reg" value="the value i want to send by post">'.$plus['FRN_RGN_VALUE'].'</a>. i just have to put a form before ? i have to put catalogue_search in the attr href directly without location (in ajax) ?

Comment: you could have clearly mentioned this in your question it was lot of confusion here.

Comment: check the answer..if thats fine with u

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
success : function () { window.location = "catalogue_search.php"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

work around with jquery if you are fine with this:

**html:**

```
<a href="#" class="search_reg" value="the value i want to send by post">click here</a>
```

**jquery:**

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("<form id='myform' action='catalogue_search.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='test' name='test' value=''/></form>").appendTo("body");
            $('.search_reg').on('click',function() {
                var value= $(this).attr("value");
                $("#test").val(value);
                $("#myform").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**update:**
you can even have this below line inside the click event. its upto you.

```
$("<form id='myform' action='catalogue_search.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='test' name='test' value=''/></form>").appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

You sending 2 separated queries, only first on(through ajax) will return POST array with your data. Second one will show you nothing, because you not sending anything.
For me best way will be add hidden form and submit it(better with native submit button). Or you can try @susheel way to do that, but for me its a bit strange.

Comment: even his requirement is strange :P :P